# Install Postgresql-server-dev on RaspberryPi (armhf) running Ubuntu Server 16.04 from source

Tags: apt, software-installation, postgresql

I am setting up my raspberry pi as a test server for a rails application. This requires PostgreSQL-server-dev to be installed, or else the pg gem won't install with capistrano. I have tried using apt-get and aptitude to install postgresql-server-dev, however, it says

```
 N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

when I try installing. I have added the repository to `pgdg.list`, however it looks like there is no port for ARM architecture available.

On the ubuntu page for postgresql, under the `port -> armhf`, there is a page, but no download link, so I believe that this is impossible to install with `apt-get`.

I have found a link for the source code [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/armhf/postgresql-server-dev-9.5/9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04) 
However I have no idea what to do with this file. Any help on how to install or workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out. `wget` to download, `apt-get` to install dependencies, and `dpkg -i` to install package itself. Pretty simple.